# Difference between open and import a project in androidstudio

Tags: android-studio

What is difference between open and import a project in android studio? Is there a way that we can do import of a project from command line or do all settings that is done while importing a project?

Answer (score 7):

**OPEN** is to open existing projects which already have been run in Android Studio.

**IMPORT** is for migrating projects from other environments to Android Studio, for more information take a look on this: [Migrating to Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Comment: Thanks Rithe for reply. I have a manually created Android Gradle project for some reasons and I want it to import to android studio. Is there a way to import using commandline?

Comment: Unfortunately i could not find anything about importing projects in command line.

Comment: which option do you use to open an android project that has just been cloned from a repository?

Comment: depends on the android project. if it's already a gradle project, you can open it. if it's not, you have to import it.